# Android Studio ¿Cómo pasar datos de una actividad tabbeada a uno de sus fragments?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una **actividad** la cual está **tabbeada** con los tabs "**Datos**" y "**Numeros**". Esta actividad al iniciarse, recibe algunos datos con el método .**putExtra** del Intent. Me gustaría poder **pasar esos mismos datos** a los distintos fragmentos "Datos" y "Numeros" pero no tengo idea de como lograrlo.

**Adjunto el código de la actividad tabbeada**

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_clases);

nombre = getIntent().getStringExtra("nombre");
url_foto = getIntent().getStringExtra("url_foto");

viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pagerr_info_clases);
tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabss_info_clases);

adapter_info adaptador = new 
adapter_info(getApplicationContext(),getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adaptador);
tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

**Adjunto la clase que realiza los cambios de fragment (clase creada por el IDE Android Studio)**

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

private model_info modelo;

//PARA RETORNAR EL FRAGMENT SELECCIONADO
public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch(index){
        case 1:
            fragment= new datos();
            break;

        case 2:
            fragment= new numeros();;
            break;
    }

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    modelo = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(model_info.class);
    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt("section_number");
    }
    modelo.setIndex(index);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_info, container, false);

    return root;
}
```

**Muchas gracias por leer**

Answer (score 0):

Usa una clase estatica

```
static class MiData {

   static Data dataname
}
```

Antes de hacer la acción de add replace o show con el fragmentManager actualiza tus datos y en el fragment ya los llamas. Google usa estáticos para pasarse datos también.